# MyBatis error converting result into Java records with an association

Tags: java, mybatis-mapper

We are moving from using Java Pojo's as DTO's to records with the MyBatis framework.

The following two record types are used:

```
public record User(Integer cprid, String inlognaam, String upn, Boolean actief, String email, Locatie locatie, Collection<RoleExtra> rolesExtra) {}

public record RoleExtra(Role role) { }
```

The identifier of a user is the cprid.
Location and Role are simple enums.

Having the following query in myBatis:

```
<select id="getAllUsers" resultMap="suezUserResult">
    SELECT g.inlognaam, g.cprid, g.upn, g.actief, g.email, g.locatie, grl.rol
    FROM suez.gebruikers g
    LEFT JOIN suez.gebruikers_rollen_link grl USING (cprid)
    WHERE cprid = 107884
    ORDER BY g.naam
</select>
```

results in the tuples:

```
 inlognaam | cprid  |             upn             | actief |            email            | locatie |   rol
-----------+--------+-----------------------------+--------+-----------------------------+---------+---------
 msmith    | 107884 | m.smith@amsterdamumc.nl     | t      | m.smith@amsterdamumc.nl     | AMC     | ROLE_PI
 msmith    | 107884 | m.smith@amsterdamumc.nl     | t      | m.smith@amsterdamumc.nl     | AMC     | ROLE_PL
```

The resultmaps used:

```
<resultMap id="suezUserResult" type="amr.bi.elsalvador.domain.suez.User">
     <constructor>
        <arg column="cprid" javaType="java.lang.Integer"/>
        <arg column="inlognaam" javaType="java.lang.String"/>
        <arg column="upn" javaType="java.lang.String"/>
        <arg column="actief" javaType="java.lang.Boolean"/>
        <arg column="email" javaType="java.lang.String"/>
        <arg column="locatie" javaType="amr.bi.elsalvador.enums.Locatie"/>
        <arg javaType="java.util.Collection" resultMap="roleExtraResult" />
    </constructor>
    <id column="cprid"/>
  </resultMap>

<resultMap type="amr.bi.elsalvador.domain.suez.RoleExtra" id="roleExtraResult">
    <constructor>
        <arg column="rol" javaType="amr.bi.elsalvador.enums.Role" />
    </constructor>
</resultMap>
```

When invoking getAllUsers I get an exception:

```
Error instantiating class amr.bi.elsalvador.domain.suez.User with invalid types
(Integer,String,String,Boolean,String,Locatie,Collection) or values 
(107884,msmith,m.smith@amsterdamumc.nl,true,m.smith@amsterdamumc.nl,AMC,**RoleExtra[role=Principal Investigator]**).
Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
```

It seems that MyBatis is trying to make two instances of User for each role ROLE_PI and ROLE_PL (hence the argument type mismatch) instead of one instance using the set of roles.
What am I doing wrong?