# MyBatis yielding Java records

Tags: java, mybatis

I am moving from Java Pojo's to Java records using MyBatis.
Is it possible in MyBatis to create a Java record which has a field of type collection?
How should the resultMap be defined?

Answer (score 0):

Possible, but with limitations.

Because records are immutable, [constructor-mapping](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#constructor) must be used.
And, to pass a `Collection` to a constructor, you have to use [nested select](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#nested-select-for-collection).
This means that if you are trying to retrieve N parent records, N+1 SELECTs will be executed.

If the N+1 problem is a blocker, you may have to use POJOs and convert them into records in the service layer or in a default method of the mapper interface.

Here is a simple example.
If this is too simple to apply to your project, please add more details to the question.

```sql
create table item (
  id int primary key,
  name varchar(10)
);

create table prop (
  id int primary key,
  url varchar(100),
  item_id int
)
```

```java
@Results(id = "propertyRM")
@Arg(id = true, column = "id", javaType = int.class)
@Arg(column = "url", javaType = String.class)
@Select("select id, url from prop where item_id = #{itemId}")
Collection<Property> selectProperties(Integer itemId);

@Arg(id = true, column = "id", javaType = Integer.class)
@Arg(javaType = Collection.class,  select = "selectProperties", column = "id")
@Select("select id, name from item")
List<Item> selectItems();
```

Here is an equivalent XML version:

```xml
<resultMap id="propertyRM" type="pkg.Property">
  <constructor>
    <idArg column="id" javaType="int" />
    <arg column="url" javaType="string" />
  </constructor>
</resultMap>

<resultMap id="itemRM" type="pkg.Item">
  <constructor>
    <idArg column="id" javaType="int" />
    <arg column="name" javaType="string" />
    <arg javaType="java.util.Collection"
      select="selectProperties" column="id" />
  </constructor>
</resultMap>

<select id="selectProperties" resultMap="propertyRM">
  select id, url from prop where item_id = #{itemId}
</select>

<select id="selectItems" resultMap="itemRM">
  select id, name from prop
</select>
```

Note that the `Collection` passed to the constructor is mutable, so if you want "deeply immutable" records, you may have to implement the constructor explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I got your example working.

Unfortenately there is a cascade of queries being fired to the database server.

For each item the properties are being queried (selectProperties) seperately.

Is it possible to change the query selectItems to retrieve everything at once (join) and change the third constructor argument into something like:

<arg javaType="java.util.Collection"
      resultMap="mapProperties" column="id" />

I tried this but it did not work. In stead of a Collection of items an item was being injected in the constructor.

Comment: This question is a spin of of another question of mine:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77563582/mybatis-error-converting-result-into-java-records-with-an-association

Comment: No, it's not possible with records (or traditional immutable class). You may have to use POJOs instead. If you have written a JDBC program that maps JOINed result set, you would understand why it's difficult to instantiate immutable objects with collections.